# Using a model that has an implicit conversion to the declared @model in a display template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Number {get; set;}
}
```

and an extended version:

```
public class ExtendedMyClass
{
   public MyClass Data {get; set;}
   public ExtendedMyClass(MyClass data)
   {
       Data = data;
   }
   public static implicit operator ExtendedMyClass(MyClass data) => return new ExtendedMyClass(data);
}
```

In the display template I have `@model ExtendedMyClass`

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
foreach(var item in AllData)/* AllData is a list that contains a mix of MyClass and ExtendedMyClass*/
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item)
}
```

But I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyClass', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ExtendedMyClass'

Is there a way for this to work without rolling a custom IModelBinder implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime doesn't know which type it's supposed to use. It only sees the original type. Just use an explicit conversion:

```
var extended = (ExtendedMyClass)item;
@Html.DisplayFor(m => extended)
```

Comment: Then I get the following: `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.` Whether I use `(MyExtendedClass)item` or `new ExtendedMyClass(item)`

Comment: This also won't work because the of "list contains a mix of MyClass and ExtendedMyClass" so the cast will fali

Comment: @Alex no, it won't. `MyClass` has an implicit operator. See http://ideone.com/S6sdGJ.